# Adicionar atributo a objeto criado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

estou tentando adicionar um `data-id` para objetos que serão criados dinamicamente, bom a questão é  que quero fazer isso logo quando o documento ou  meu objeto for carregado, sem a necessidade de clicar etc, veja da maneira que eu tentei.

Por exemplo:

```
$(document).on('ready','.letras',function(){

    $(this).attr('data-id',faixas2[k]['id_faixa']);



    });
```

ou

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){

$('.letras').attr('data-id',faixas2[k]['id_faixa']);



    });
```

não rola de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Qual seria o conteúdo do faixa2?

Comment: O melhor seria fazer isso no momento em que o objeto é criado. Quando dizes _"criado dinamicamente"_ podes mostrar o código que faz isso?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo código creio que a quantidade de itens no array faixas2 seja igual a quantidade de classes e que você pretende atribuir esses valores nas divs com a classe `.letras`, o método `.each` tem o argumento onde você recebe o índice.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var faixas = ["faixaA", "faixaB", "faixaC"];

  $(".letras").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("data-id", faixas[index]);
  });
});
```

```css
.letras {
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #6a737c;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="letras">A</div>
<div class="letras">B</div>
<div class="letras">C</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Com jQuery, pode fazer utilizando o [**each**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), veja um exemplo abaixo, onde após a execução, todos os elementos com a classe letras recebe um atributo chamado `data-id` com o valor do array `valores`:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.letras').each(function(indice_do_array){
        var valores = ["Teste1", "Teste2", "Teste3", "Teste4"];
        $(this).attr('data-id',valores[indice_do_array]);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class="letras">Teste 1</li>
  <li class="letras">Teste 2</li>
  <li class="letras">Teste 3</li>
  <li class="letras">Teste 4</li>
</ul>
```